# Including a code behind file in another .cs file in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am writing a code, and i have a web form called Default.aspx and have a code behind file Default.aspx.cs and added some textboxes, buttons etc. to it. Now i created another .cs item called University.cs and want to include Default.aspx in University.cs to use the values in the textboxes. Here is the code for Default.aspx.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}






protected void LoginAs_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
protected void loginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
    con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=d:\\CourseRegistration\\WebSite1\\App_Data\\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";


    Int32 verify;
    string query1 = "Select count(*) from LoginTable where ID='" + idBox.Text + "' and Password='" + passwordBox.Text + "' and Type='" + LoginAs.SelectedValue + "'";
    SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(query1, con);
    con.Open();
    verify = Convert.ToInt32(cmd1.ExecuteScalar());
    con.Close();
    if (verify > 0)
    {
        if (LoginAs.SelectedValue == "Administrator")
            Response.Redirect("Admin.aspx");
        else if (LoginAs.SelectedValue == "Student")
            Response.Redirect("Student.aspx");
        else if (LoginAs.SelectedValue == "Instructor")
            Response.Redirect("Instructor.aspx");
    }
    else
    {
        idBox.Text = "";
        LoginError.Visible = true;
    }

}
}
```

I can use all textboxes, buttons etc. in this Default.aspx.cs file but they are not usable in University.cs file. I tried to write **using Default.aspx.cs** but it did not work. What can i do about this?

Thank you

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: **Do not store password in plain text**

Comment: @SLaks thanks i will take care of it later

Comment: Why do you want to have University.cs be able to do this? The reason that the elements are not accessible is due to scoping and/or access modifiers, which basically means that you (probably) shouldn't be trying to do what you're trying to do in that way.

Comment: @TimS. i am trying to get the value of a textBox so i want to be able to reach it.

Comment: @bigO: You should have your .aspx call methods in the univesity.cs file passing whatever data is needed as parameters or something similar to that. .aspx files are there to render the screen and so make no sense to include in a .cs (at least not in the way you are talking anyway).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot include a aspx class in a .cs class. You would instead have to try passing the data through some other means (eg: Session, application variable, storing the data in cookies, etc).